# Python Appegine sys.path.append() doesnt work

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I'm not finding a correct way to add "libs" to my system path. So, I want to import:

```
from lib1 import ClassX
```

In main.py:

```
import os, sys
sys.path.append(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "libs"))
```

My project schema is:

```
project
--- app1
--- libs
------ lib1.py
------ __init__.py
--- main.py
```

How can I achieve this?

**UPDATE!**
I have used. Same error:

```
sys.path.append("/home/alpocr/path-to-project/libs")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A more comprehensive and complete solution is available via the [Darth Vendor](https://github.com/jonparrott/Darth-Vendor) utility. You can read about some of the challenges and pitfalls with a simple `sys.path.append` [here](http://blog.jonparrott.com/managing-vendored-packages-on-app-engine/).

Hopefully in the near future it will be easier to manage 3rd party packages on app engine.

Answer (score 0):

add `os.path.abspath` to your code:

```
import os, sys
sys.path.append(
   os.path.join(
      os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__),
      "libs"
   )
)
```

Comment: Thanks Alex. Same error. "ImportError: No module named lib1"

Comment: Fixed! I have created appengine_config.py into root directory.